# AT command - USSD

Tags: at-command, ussd

I'm using [Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) (serial port software for Linux) for interacting with my GSM modem. Actually now I'm trying to use one of my mobile-provider's services with AT commands.

Here I say, I want to see my balance:

```
AT+CUSD=1,*555*87*1234#

OK

+CUSD: 1,"this service will deduct you 5cent from your balance, to continue please enter 1",15
```

So, here I sent "1", but nothing happened and the session got closed.

```
AT+CUSD=1,1

OK
```

Nothing happened, but the session closed.

With a normal phone, after entering 1, I will get my current balance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The format of the command is `AT+CUSD=[<n>[,<str>[,<dcs>]]]`, and the second parameter, `<str>`, is a string that should be enclosed in double quotes. E.g.

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*555*87*1234#"
AT+CUSD=1,"1"
```

See [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more details about `AT+CUSD` and [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) for general AT command handling.

---

If your phone gives an `OK` response to `AT+CUSD=1,1` that is really bad, it should have given `ERROR`. V.250 is crystal clear on this:

> String constants
>   shall be bounded at the beginning and end by the double-quote character

Comment: the problem is solved :) actually my account was zero at first, and normally I should have received an error saying that "my balance is not enough", anyway after I transferred the money to my account, I've tested again and now I see the confirmation message and ..

Answer (score 13):

```
AT+CUSD=1,"your_service_code",15
```

So for your case,

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*555*87*1234#",15
```

And don't forget the 15 at the end. This question helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Works for SIM900a GSM Module. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain about `15`?

Comment: @hong4rc 15 is encoding scheme as per GSM 3.38 , more info here https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/ussd-how-to-send-ussd-short-codes-with-at-command/