# AT+CUSD Command for Multiple Menu: Session closes and I can't get to the second menu

Tags: at-command, ussd

AT Command for USSD with Multiple Menu.

When I check on normal mobile I have to follow the command like this -

```
USSD Command - *401*1*22#
```

I got a reply as

```
Welcom to ---. You Will receive the menu shortly. Please exit
```

after few second I got a menu as

```
1 Bill Payments 
2 Others 
Reply with your choice
Here I got two button as "Answer" and "Back"
```

I have to click on "Answer" and reply with "1" for the next MENU.

I try the AT Command as follows

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*401*1*22#",15
AT+CUSD=1,"1",15
```

I got the message as -

```
+CUSD: 2,"Welcom to ---. You Will receive the menu shortly. Please exit",15
+CUSD: 1,"1 Bill Payments2 OthersReply with your choice",15
```

Here **the session closes** and I am **unable** to get to the next menu.

How can I move to the next menu after replying 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850819/at-command-ussd? This question seems to describe the same problem.

Comment: @sashoalm thanks for ur reply. I too hope that the question are similar. but it does not solve my problem. In my case I have first click on the Answer button and type 1 for reply. I have also try as per there answer.

Comment: "but it does not solve my problem" - please elaborate. Why didn't it solve your problem? Describe how you tried following the solution and why it didn't work. Maybe try removing the ",15" at the end? Also, what programming language are you using? It would be better if you pasted the actual code that generates those commands.

Comment: In most of the USSD Command when we give the first command and need for reply than it automatically open the text box and we have to simply type the number and sent it. for example the first command is *111*2# and it will automatically open the text box for reply and we have to write it 1 and reply it. But in my case I have already mention in my question that when i give my first command *401*1*22# it doesnot open the text box for reply, I have to press the "Answer" button and then it open the text box for reply, here I have to write 1 and reply it.

Comment: Ok. What about the programming language? Can you post the code?

Comment: I am using Microsoft HyperTerminal to Send AT Commands to a Mobile Phone or GSM/GPRS Modem

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: AT+CUSD=1,"*401*1*22#",15
OK
+CUSD: 2,"Welcom to ---. You Will receive the menu shortly. Please exit",15
+CUSD: 1,"1 Bill Payments2 OthersReply with your choice",15
AT+CUSD=1,"1",15

Answer (score 0):

AT+CUSD=1,"*401*1*22#",15

After u receive menu and choose as follows.

> 1

and press ctrl+z