# How to send AT commands using to USB modem on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

like this command: `*342*55*225*5#`

I installed Ubuntu and minicom on it. I tried to follow the guide written in [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/modem-at-command/),
but I was blocked because when I entered AT and clicked enter, it did not respond...

On python I was following up a method but when I entered this command

```
comport = serial.Serial('ttyUSB4')
```

I got this error :

```
self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ttyUSB4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide full path to device:

```
comport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB4')
```

But prefer udev paths, they will not change if you plug in devices in other order:

```
comport = serial.Serial('/dev/serial/by-id/<nameofyourdevice>')
```

Comment: thank you this worked , now how could I dial this : *436*1*2*68504759#?

Comment: @akramdahab So, if it worked, please accept my answer (click on the green tick).

Comment: could you help on how to dial this kind of codes : *436*1*2*68504759#

Comment: @akramdahab  There is special AT command ("AT+CUSD") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850819/at-command-ussd