# USSD Response Reply with GSM modem and C#

Tags: c#, at-command

I can access gsm modem using C# and AT commands.

After sending: `AT+CUSD=1,"*789#",15`, it responses with:

> +CUSD: 1,"Welcome to Power Menu
>
> 1. Amar Tune
> 2. Internet
> 3. Self Services
> 4. Infotainment
> 5. News
> 6. Islamic Services
> 7. Music Station
> 8. More 0: Back H: MainMenu",64

I want to go to menu 3 like `3. Self Services`. But how do I reply to it. Could you help me?

Comment: Already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850819/at-command-ussd

Comment: I have read, but not working, always response +CUSD: 2

Comment: Im working on something similar, do you mind sharing your code ? Im getting errors when running the commands.